# JOIN in 4 tables gets phpmyadmin unresponsive

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin

I can´t manage to create a valid query that shows me 5 columns from these 4 tables:

[image]

As you can see the relationships that i'm trying to JOIN in the query are highlighted in differents colors.

The query i came out is:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName
, s.categoryname
, cprs.strenght 
, s.parentid
, ss.Risklevel
, ss.ColumnType

FROM company_details AS c
JOIN category_master AS s ON s.id = c.categoryid
JOIN company_strenght AS cprs ON cprs.companyid = c.id
JOIN subsector_detasils AS ss ON s.parentid = ss.subcategoryid
```

But server gets unresponsive until i have to kill the process. 
The issue is in the last line, if i remove it and only manage 3 tables i get a successful result but is not enough for what i want.

**Problem description:**
The *company_details* table is a list of companies. The `id` field is an unique ID that each company has. 
We need to match that id with the `companyid` field in the *company_strenght* table so we can get the `c.CompanyName, s.categoryname, cprs.strenght` columns. All good so far.

Then we need to include in the results the *category_master* table which contains the category that each company belongs to. So we match `s.id = c.categoryid`for that. Still no problem and i get a list of companies with the catergories they belong to and also their parent category id.

**Finally here is the problem:** Each company has a parent category which id is `parentid` in the *category_master* table (marked in green). This `parentid` field is the same than the `subcategoryid` field in the *subsector_detasils* table. 
We need to match `s.parentid = ss.subcategoryid` so we can get `ss.Risklevel, ss.ColumnType` columns in the results. But as i said, it's not working since phpmyadmin just stops working and i have to kill the process manually.

Is there any other way to get around this problem? I'm running out of ideas...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the indexes, preferably via `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely something more like this,but I'm not sure if you want to use `INNER JOIN`s or not:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName
, s.categoryname
, cprs.strenght 
, s.parentid
, ss.Risklevel
, ss.ColumnType

FROM (
       (
         company_details AS c INNER JOIN category_master AS s ON s.id = c.categoryid
       ) INNER JOIN company_strenght AS cprs ON cprs.companyid = c.id
     ) INNER JOIN subsector_detasils AS ss ON s.parentid = ss.subcategoryid
```

make sure you're sure it's what you want, and I would consider sorting it as well to make sure everything you're expecting is there...

Also, to make this more readable, you might consider using some pre-made `VIEW`s, using a `CREATE <view-name> VIEW AS <one-inner-join>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But still no result from the query it becomes unresponsive after several minutes.
I could use INNER JOIN, no problem on that. Does the `( )` change something specific, or did you make any other change that i'm missing since the query looks pretty much the same...

Comment: @gallo2000sv Try splitting the joins into `VIEW`s or add a `LIMIT` clause for the first 10 results, just to see if it works at all.

Comment: @gallo2000sv The `()` group together an `inner join` statement so that it's like one table, or one query, or one view.

Comment: You should probably change your fields to a `count(*)` so you can see how many records would be returned.  The query is likely timing out before it returns.  I didn't actually test it out, I took your code and made a guess based on the ERD you uploaded.

Comment: In MySQL, `INNER JOIN` is identical to `JOIN`.  And I doubt if the parentheses make any difference in this case.

Comment: Adding a `LIMIT 10` may not help -- if it is spending lots of time _before_ getting to the `LIMIT`.

Comment: Even though I suspected  the _parentheses_ and `inner` doesn't affect the query   as @Rick James said. It seems to be working with the `LIMIT` clause. 
I think it's a hardware problem trying to use too much RAM to retrieve so many rows. 
**SOLUTION:** I will try to split the the JOINS and will use a temporary table to improve the performance and reduce the processing time. 
Thanks a lot for the insights :)

Comment: Right; take a key from another “Rick James” and “break it down” into ‘VIEW’s or temporary tables.

Comment: Another thing you can do it create a filter on date range so that it only pulls that date range; that will also limit the number of records returned.